# Enable debug in release builds

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-studio-2012

What is my problem is basically, when I run the following code in a Debug build, I am getting a `index out of range` exception:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
     QApplication app(argc, argv);
     QStringList test();
     QInfo() << test.at(3);
     app.exec();
}
```

The problem is, when I build in the release mode and try to run the application, nothing happends, no prompt messages, no crash - just a silent exit.

Hence I though I need to enable debug mode - I did so:

1. Set Debug Information Format to Program Database (/Zi)
2. Set Enable Incremental Linking to No (/INCREMENTAL:NO)
3. Set Generate Debug Info to Yes (/DEBUG)
4. Set References to Yes (/OPT:REF)
5. Set Generate Map File to Yes (/MAP)Yes (/MAP)
6. Set Map Exports to Yes (/MAPINFO:EXPORTS)

There is still no effect though when I try to launch my app. So how can I enable this?

Comment: Turn optimizations off.

Comment: IIRC thats an assert (macro) which is compiled-out in release mode (`#define assert() //nothing`)

Comment: @tkausl True `assert(_Expression)     ((void)0)`, however I'm not sure if there's an assert in this particular case.

Comment: @AndyG Had them off all the time.

Comment: @tkausl It doesn't seems like it's an assert, defined own assert and still no effects: `#undef assert
#define assert(x) QMessageBox::critical(nullptr,"Error", "Assert");`

Comment: Note: Your example doesn't need the `QApplication` instance nor  the `app.exec()` call. Qt Containers can be used without an application instance. An extreme example of this: a colleague of mine has a bunch of QString-using code in a Linux kernel module (don't ask).

Comment: Why can't you use a debug build?

Comment: It is unclear, why you want anything to happen. Accessing an element of `QList` that is outside the valid range is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior can exhibit any behavior. The error message you get for a debug build is from a [Q_ASSERT_X](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#Q_ASSERT_X). As documented, *"it does nothing if `QT_NO_DEBUG` was defined during compilation."* To get the the same effect for a release build, you'd have to link against Qt's debug libraries. That's likely not possible due to incompatibilities.